# Is appmaker accessible to people from outside the organisation?

Tags: google-app-maker

I want to build an ATS with appmaker. We would use Google FORMS to get all information needed from both candidates and clients, but we would also like to give them "granular" access to the system, without having an email of ours.

Is that possible, or is appmaker only for internal systems?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATS - which one =) ? By the way, App Maker app deployments are available only inside your domain/organization at this time, I hope it'll change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, AppMaker limits use to users under your GSuite domain.

AppMaker is still in beta, so hopefully, future releases will expand user access to your AppMaker application.